# Visual simulation of elementary particles and interactions thererof?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, simulations, interactions

Pardon me for a very stupid question,

but knowing that SM predicts so much about sub-atomic particles, their interactions and whatnot, means that we have formalized these into some sorts of equations, meaning that we can plug these equations in a simulation and use that to predict new unseen behaviours (maybe?).
Is there some sort of "accurate-enough" simulation of, say, hydrogen atom, consiting down to elementary particles and their interactions, existing in a 3D space of some sort of "quantum foam"?
If no, why? What is missing?

Comment: Better people than I can reply to your post, but the  SM, AFAIK, is a catalogue of properties, rather than any predictive mechanism. If you wanted something specifically to aim at, it would be to try and obtain a dark matter entity from the the SM, which is difficult. Also, supersymmetry has not not been experientially found, despite efforts to extend the SM. But best of luck with a nice question. Quantum foam is a bit handwavy, no offence, the SM deals with real, rather than virtual articles. Again, you need an expert answer, which I can't provide

Comment: Also, you might consider the 20 plus parameters that are experimental results, needed to make the SM work.  That's a lot of wriggle rooom for predictions, when you really need a dirty fingernailed, screwdriver behind the ear, experimentalist, imo....:)